# KEEPING a field "null" unless other information has been put in it through a form in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, null

How do you preset fields so that (unless a specific value is entered from the form itself) they STAY null? For another project, I will later have to pull information from this table depending on what options people choose, so if I could do a cfif against nulls I think it'd be a lot easier than the blanks that are currently generated if I don't insert any new values.

Does anyone know where/how to do this? I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio to edit what the individual columns, and all I can find are the command codes using INSERT, SELECT, etc., rather than having a list that I edit. Or is that the only way to make my default setting be "null"?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What you're describing is default behaviour.  Please let us know the conditions under which you're getting different results so we can give you more specific help.

Comment: Okay, um... Well I tried to set a default value of (NULL) to the column, but that didn't work, it was still coming in as a blank space. I can make the value be "null" but it's not the **actual** null value (it just happens to say null) - is this making it clearer? I'm not sure what you're asking for about "different results"

Comment: How are you inserting values and getting empty strings?

Comment: I have checkboxes, which open options for people to either select a value from a dropdown (which is where I can see having an empty string issue, just no idea how to solve that), or type it in themselves. If either of those are left blank, it leaves a blank in the table. I got my true/false boolean values to work using CFSET; is this a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

If a field is set to be a nullable field (that is, it allows `NULL`), when adding a row, it will be `NULL` unless otherwise specified.

You don't need to do anything special for this.

If your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements simply omit the field, it will not be updated, though you can specifically specify `NULL` for such a field if wanted.

Comment: There are two circumstances where it will not automatically be null even if the table allows null - if a default value has been set inteh table definition or if you are sending in a blank value  through the query in the user interface.

Comment: I have it set up that way... they are set to take nulls, but instead of that italicized null it is just a blank space in the table. Does that mean I have something in my form that I need to change so that it doesn't just assume there's a blank value instead of staying null?

Comment: @SJ - What form are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper function to handle parameter setup.  This is a simplified version of a function I use...

```
private static object ProcessParameter(object input)
{
    if (input == null)
        return input;

    switch (input.GetType().ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "system.string":
            if (input == null || input.ToString() == "") { return DBNull.Value; }
            return input;

        case "system.int32":
        case "system.double":
            if (input.ToString() == "0" && IsNullable(input)) { return DBNull.Value; }
            return input;

        case "system.datetime":
            if (System.Convert.ToDateTime(input) == DateTime.MinValue || System.Convert.ToDateTime(input) == default(DateTime)) { return DBNull.Value; }
            return input;

        default:
            return input;
    }
}
```